# how i enable/disable push notification in specific selected time period in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

i want to turn of push notification from my app itself during my selected time periods, i am new in ios development please help me in, how can i do this....
I have no idea for that...

i am going to select time from timepicker and when i press ok it would open setting from iphone.

[image]

```
    func openTimePicker()  {
    timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    timePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: (self.view.frame.height/2 + 60), width: self.view.frame.width, height: 150.0)
    timePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(timePicker)
    timePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourViewControllerName.startTimeDiveChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}
```

Comment: It would be better to do this with the help of the backend.

Comment: @Frankenstein but i just have to select it from timepicker that's it, there is no requirement to use with backend.

Comment: Unless you are using silent push notifications to create a local notification you can't do it on the device.

Comment: Sorry you can't do such a thing from device, you need to configure it from backend.